# Audio element on page not playing

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have a javascript book component that I can use to turn the page. When I click on a page the page is flipped and the next page appears.

I wrote an application that I can embed an audio file, through an `audio` element, in each page. My problem is that when I want to click on the `audio` element to play the sound, instead the page is flipped.

I wrote javascript code that prevents continuing to flip the page like this:

```js
$('.page').click(function(e) {
  /******************** I wrote from here **************************/
  mousePosition = {
    x: e.clientX,
    y: e.clientY
  }

  var elementsArray = document.elementsFromPoint(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
  for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
    //loop through elementsArray until you find the td you're interested in
    if (elementsArray[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === "audio")
      return;
  }
  /************************** To here ************************/

  var page = $(this);
  var page_num = pages.index(page) + 1;
  if (page_num % 2 === 0) {
    page.removeClass('flipped');
    page.prev().removeClass('flipped');
  } else {
    page.addClass('flipped');
    page.next().addClass('flipped');
  }
});
```

The code works and when I am on the `audio` element page does not turn. The problem is that the `audio` element is not played and I can't work with its controls! How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a style rule content:: "" i disabled and now it works. The rule is:

```
.bound .page:before {
            /*content: "";*/
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            transition: background 0.7s;
            z-index: 2;
        }
```

But a better solution is to leave content: "" enabled and add this style to audio element itself:

```
style='z-index: 3 !important; display: inline-block; position:relative;'
```

for being complete this is the updated javascript code:

```
$('.pageb').click(function (e) {           
            mousePosition = {
                x: e.clientX,
                y: e.clientY
            }           

            var elementsArray = document.elementsFromPoint(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
            for (var i = 0; i < elementsArray.length; i++) {
                //loop through elementsArray until you find the td you're interested in
                var elName = elementsArray[i].nodeName.toLowerCase();
                if ((elName === "audio" || elName === "video") && elementsArray[i].parentNode == this) {                   
                    return;
                }
            }
            
                var page = $(this);
                var page_num = pages.index(page) + 1;
                if (page_num % 2 === 0) {
                    page.removeClass('flipped');
                    page.prev().removeClass('flipped');
                } else {
                    page.addClass('flipped');
                    page.next().addClass('flipped');
            }            
            });
```